# Can I use UNION to create a view that combines multiple columns from various other tables for each column in the view?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working in Snowflake with a raw vault layer that contains data about an organisations travel journeys (air, rail, hotel stay, car rental). In the raw vault, each type of journey e.g. rail, air, hotel, car, has its own table and there are two travel agencies for this organisation so there are essentially two tables per type od journey (table 1 for travel agency X, journey type being air travel and table 2 for travel agency Y, journey type being air travel).

I want to make a view with the following columns:
-- travel skey,
-- mode of transport,
-- company(hotel chain, car company, airline)
-- departure location (air departure airport and rail origin station),
-- arrival location (air destination airport, rail destination station, hotel city),
-- class (airline class, rail class),
-- hotel property name (,
-- arrival region (air trip destination region)

The columns in the brackets are the columns I want to combine to form each column. For example, I want to make the column 'Company' in the view which will combine the columns hotel_chain, car_company, and airline from the raw vault - these three columns are in separate tables.

To illustrate, I want to do the following for each of the columns in the view:

| Hotel Chain. |
| --- |
| Mariot |
| Hyatt |

| Car Company |
| --- |
| Hertz |
| Enterprise |

| Airline |
| --- |
| American Airlines |
| British Airways |

| Company |
| --- |
| Mariot |
| Hyatt |
| Hertz |
| Enterprise |
| American Airlines |
| British Airways. |

I have tried the following SQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DIM_TRAVEL AS
WITH 
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'HOTEL_CHAIN' AS Company FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_hotel_stay
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'car_company' AS Company FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_car_rentals
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'carrier_code' AS Company FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_flight
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'carrier' AS Company FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_flight
    ),
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'origin_code' AS 'Departure Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_flight
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'origin_airport_code' AS 'Departure Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_flight
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'origin' AS 'Departure Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_rail_journey
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'from' AS 'Departure Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_rail_journey
    ),
    cte3 AS (
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'destination_code' AS 'Arrival Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_flight
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'destination_airport_code' AS 'Arrival Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_flight
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'destination' AS 'Arrival Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_rail_journey
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'to' AS 'Arrival Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_rail_journey
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'hotel_city' AS 'Arrival Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_hotel_stay
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'city' AS 'Arrival Location' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_hotel_stay
    ),
    cte4 AS (
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'travel_class' AS 'Class' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_rail_journey
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'travel_class' AS 'Class' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_rail_journey
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'travel_class' AS 'Class' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_flight
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'travel_class' AS 'Class' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_flight
    ),
    cte5 AS (
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'property_name' AS 'Hotel Property Name' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_hotel_stay
        UNION
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'hotel_name' AS 'Hotel Property Name' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_reed_mackay_hotel_stay
    ),
    cte6 AS (
        SELECT 'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT', 'travel_region' AS 'Arrival Region' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.lsat_frosch_flight
    )

    cte7 AS (
        SELECT SK AS 'Travel Skey' FROM RB_DEFAULT_030_RVT.link_travel_event)
SELECT 
    a.Company, b.'Departure Location', c.'Arrival Location', d.'Class', e.'Hotel Property Name', f.'Arrival Region'
FROM 
    cte1 a
LEFT JOIN 
    cte2 b ON a.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT' = b.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT'
LEFT JOIN 
    cte3 c ON b.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT' = c.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT'
LEFT JOIN 
    cte4 d ON c.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT' = d.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT'
LEFT JOIN 
    cte5 e ON d.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT' = e.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT'
LEFT JOIN 
    cte6 f ON e.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT' = f.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT'
LEFT JOIN
    cte7 g ON f.'HK_JOURNEY_EVENT' = g.HK;


I haven't run it yet as the raw vault hasn't been built yet in our Snowflake env but I am hoping someone can let me know if I am going about this the right way?
```

Comment: Yes you probably can do what you're suggesting but what's overall result you are trying to achieve? It's not clear why you've written this as multiple CTEs that you join together, why select all the columns you need from each table in a single query (for each table) UNION'd  in one CTE?